# Linear transformation and ordered basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation defined by $$T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(2x_1-x_2+2x_3,x_1+x_2,3x_1-x_2-x_3)$$
> Consider the two bases  $B=\{(1,0,0),(1,1,1),(1,-1,1)\}$ and $C=\{(1,1,2),(1,2,1),(2,1,1)\}$  of $\Bbb{R}^3$
>
> Find the matrix representation of T which is ${R_{B,C}}({3 \times 3})$ 'with respect to' B and C.

I'm not sure If I correctly translated the question. Maybe 'with respect to' should be replaced by 'in terms of'.

---

The answer is acquired like this,
$T(1,0,0)=(2,1,3)=3/2(1,1,2)-1/2(1,2,1)+1/2(2,1,1)$,
and the first row of R is $\{3/2,-1/2,1\}$.

I'm confused what $R$ or $R_{B,C}$ means and why the solution work like this.

**(Edit)**  B and C are said to be ordered bases.

Comment: Actually the coefficients are written as column vectors instead of row vectors

Comment: How should I correct it?

Comment: I think you know how to compute the matrix of $R$, so the only question is : Why they work"? Am I right?

Comment: It seems columns of B equals to the linear combination of columns of C and coefficents are the rows of R, that is $B=CR^{T}$. What does it mean?

Comment: And are $R$ and $R_B,C$ some kind of universal terms? Then what do they represent?

Comment: Surely this notation is defined somewhere earlier in the material that this exercise came from. At a guess, $R_{B,C}$ is the matrix that computes $T$ when the vector being transformed is expressed relative to $B$ and the result is expressed relative to $C$. It might be the other way around, but the only way to know for sure is to find where this notation is defined in the material that you’re studying.